# Spring-boot project giving "Application run failed" error

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have a spring-boot maven project that is giving `Application run failed` (`java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: logger`) error.

When I run this application using `mvn spring-boot:run -pl application`, here's what I get:

```
2018-06-13 16:09:17.439  WARN 9069 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.e.EventPublishingRunListener     : Error calling ApplicationEventListener

java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: logger
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:248) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionEvaluationReport.get(ConditionEvaluationReport.java:169) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener.logAutoConfigurationReport(ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener.java:96) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener.onApplicationEvent(ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener.java:80) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener$ConditionEvaluationReportListener.onApplicationEvent(ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener.java:137) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) [spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:158) [spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) [spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127) [spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.failed(EventPublishingRunListener.java:126) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.callFailedListener(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:91) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.failed(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:84) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:812) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at hello.app.Application.main(Application.java:31) [classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:496) [spring-boot-maven-plugin-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) [na:na]

2018-06-13 16:09:17.446 ERROR 9069 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: logger
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:248) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionEvaluationReport.get(ConditionEvaluationReport.java:169) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener.initialize(ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener.java:65) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:633) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:373) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:325) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at hello.app.Application.main(Application.java:31) [classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:496) [spring-boot-maven-plugin-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) [na:na]

[WARNING]
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:496)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:844)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: logger
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:248)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:204)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionEvaluationReport.get (ConditionEvaluationReport.java:169)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener.initialize (ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener.java:65)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers (SpringApplication.java:633)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext (SpringApplication.java:373)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:325)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1255)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1243)
    at hello.app.Application.main (Application.java:31)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:496)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:844)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.981 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-06-13T16:09:17-07:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.1.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project multimoduletest2-app: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: logger -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

This project is a derivation of https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/.

My project structure is:

```
multimoduletest2
├── application
│   ├── pom.xml
│   ├── src
│   │   └── main
│   │       └── java
│   │           └── hello
│   │               └── app
│   │                   └── Application.java
│   └── target
│       ├── classes
│       │   └── hello
│       │       └── app
│       │           └── Application.class
│       ├── generated-sources
│       │   └── annotations
│       ├── maven-archiver
│       │   └── pom.properties
│       ├── maven-status
│       │   └── maven-compiler-plugin
│       │       └── compile
│       │           └── default-compile
│       │               ├── createdFiles.lst
│       │               └── inputFiles.lst
│       └── multimoduletest2-app-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
└── pom.xml
```

`multimoduletest2/pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>multimoduletest2</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>application</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

`multimoduletest2/application/pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.spoken</groupId>
    <artifactId>multimoduletest2-app</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>multimoduletest2</artifactId>
        <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

`Application.java`:

```
package hello.app;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

/**
 * This class implements the main function.
 */
@RestController
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "hello")
public class Application {
    /**
     * This method represents the homepage.
     *
     * @return String
     */
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String getHome() {
        return "Welcome!";
    }

    /**
     * Main
     *
     * @param args Command-line args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

This is a simplified version of a multi-module project that is giving me the same error. I'm fairly new to `spring-boot` and `maven`, so it's possible I'm overlooking something simple.

Here are some of the things I've already tried without success:

- Searched online if anyone had a similar issue
- Removed `~/.m2/repository` directory
- Checked if there are any version collisions in the dependencies
- Looked at the answer given at [Spring boot starting error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50078572/spring-boot-starting-error), but I didn't see any existing process using port 8080

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: You are mixing spring versions don't do that. Instead of spring-web include the `spring-boot-starter-web` and make sure that all the versions you use from Spring Boot match. If not you will use different versions of a framework together and that is trouble waiting to happen (regardless of the framework).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use the `spring-boot-starter-xxx` artifacts you also have to use as a parent the `spring-boot-starter-parent`.

So you have to change the `<parent>` part of your `pom.xml`

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>multimoduletest2</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

to:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

I downloaded your `pom`s and `Application.java` and had the same error as yours till I changed the `<parent>` part, then the application loaded fine. The `logger` jar is included in this `spring-boot-starter-parent` artifact.

**EDIT**
Also remove from your parent `pom` the `spring-web` dependency and add the appropriate `spring-boot` dependency in your child `pom`.

So the 2 `poms` should look like:

**parent pom:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>multimoduletest2</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>application</module>
    </modules>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**child pom:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.spoken</groupId>
    <artifactId>multimoduletest2-app</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```